# Odd behaivor on mobile drop down using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've built a custom mobile menu using CSS and jQuery, however I'm experiencing some odd behavior on the expand/collapse. SlideToggle() unintentionally opens and closes a few times in a row. It's sometimes difficult to get it to act up, but if you attempt to open and close the "Services" tab several times you will experience the bug.

Does anyone have any advise to correct this issue or a better way to skin the cat?

[JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9bfg1u7/18/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
     $("nav li:has(ul.sub-menu) a").addClass('expandable');
     $("nav li:has(ul.sub-menu)").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("a").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
      $(this).parent("li").children('ul').slideToggle();
         return false;
        });
     });        

});
```

```css
body { font-size:20px; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; }
nav { background-color:#0073ae; padding:20px; }
nav ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
nav ul li { }
nav ul li a { color:white; text-decoration:none; }
nav > ul > li > ul > li { padding-bottom:10px; margin-bottom:10px; }
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a { display:block; margin-bottom:5px; font-weight:900; }
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul { font-size:.8em; list-style:square; margin-left:15px; } 
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li { color:#f7a11a; }
nav.mobile { font-size:130%; text-transform:uppercase; }
nav.mobile > ul > li { font-weight:700; border-bottom:1px dotted white;  }
nav.mobile > ul > li > a { display:block; padding:7px 0; }
nav.mobile > ul > li > a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:white;  }
nav.mobile > ul > li > a.expandable:before { content:"+"; margin-right:10px; }
nav.mobile > ul > li > a:before, nav.mobile > ul > li > a.open:before { content:"-"; margin-right:10px; }
nav.mobile > ul > li > ul { font-size:80%; margin-left:20px; margin-top:10px; display:none; }
nav.mobile > ul > li > ul > li { padding-bottom:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu-main-menu-container mobile">
<ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu-main-menu">
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Title 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Submenu Title 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a stop() to your slideToggle.  Since slideToggle is an animation, it will continue until it stops naturally, or you force it to stop.  Clicking on "services" 5 times quickly will tell the slideToggle to animate 5 times no matter what, which is giving you the undesirable results.  You always want to stop the animation that's in progress before you start another one on the same element.

change:

```
$(this).parent("li").children('ul').slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(this).parent("li").children('ul').stop().slideToggle();
```